# I live in Nevada but work in another state

Tags: taxes, state-income-tax

I was working and living in IA but recently moved to NV and now I am working remotely. In my last paycheck I noticed no state tax was withheld.
I understand next April I will have to file taxes for each state in which income is earned. But since right now I am not paying any taxes in IA, will I get a penalty for underpayment?

Comment: was the zero state tax withheld only for that paycheck, or was that true for the whole year?

Comment: for that paycheck only, and I assume for following paychecks

Comment: Where's IA?  Can't you bother to spell out the actual names of states?  You'd have to look up the nonresident tax policies of whatever state IA happens to be.  If your employer has offices in several states, you might simply be treated as a Nevada resident for tax purposes.